# Remove characters in a file (bash).

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have several files with different columns and different separators per column (comma, space, and tab). I need to remove the first 10 characters of all the rows of a specific column. I know that for example sed ‘s/……….//’ can do the trick, but, how can I indicate the column that I want, and, how I can specify the separator of my file. Perhaps is easier to do it with awk? With awk I know how to specify the column but not how to erase the first 10 characters. Thanks.

Comment: If you provide an example that would help...

Comment: Please provide an example of input and desired output.

Comment: awk has function `substr()` available. You could do something like `awk '{$3=substr($3,1,10);print $0}` (assuming field 3, obviously). Check out [this nifty page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) that has all of the awk string functions explained for more.

Comment: The example is very straight forward... Imagine a file with 3 columns and 10 rows. I want to remove the first 10 characters of the second row for example. The separator of the columns can be in "," space and tab....

Comment: `different columns and different separators per column?` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Are you saying you have a line like `a,b<space>c<tab>d` or something else? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a front removing function and more separators in `FS`:

```
$ cat > test.in # \t below is really a tab
12345678901 2,3\t4

$ cat > test.awk
function ftrunc(str) {  # this function removes up to 10 first chars of a named field
  gsub(/^.{1,10}/,"",str)
  return str
}
BEGIN {
FS="[, \t]"             # look at me! look at me! look at me!
OFS="|"
}
{
    print ftrunc($1),ftrunc($2),$3,$4
}

$ awk -f test.awk test.in
1||3|4
```

Answer (score 4):

The first part of your question, how to erase the first 10 characters of a field, one way is like this:

```
$ echo 1234567890ABCDEF | awk '{$1=substr($1,11)}1'
ABCDEF
```

Fields with 10 or less characters will end up empty.

Second, to specify the field separator, assuming you want to keep the same separator in the output, it's best to use the `BEGIN` block and set the `FS` and `OFS` built-in awk variables.

In this example we remove the first 10 characters from the second field of a comma-separated record:

```
$ echo field1,1234567890ABCDEF,field3 | awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {$2=substr($2,11)}1'
field1,ABCDEF,field3
```

(For tab-separated: `BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}`)